Is there a system log for the XProtectService daemon actions?
I need to check the app name that provoked the launch of a XProtectService window "Verifying "[appname]"". Imposible to see live, because the window pops up and disappears almost instantly.
Is there an specific log where I can get it? (I checked, contemporaneously with the event, Console, system.log, etc, but I couldn't find anything).

Check out Howard Oakley's page of utilities. There's one that specifically reports XProtectService logs.
Also, his website is a veritable goldmine of information related to macOS security systems. Well worth a read.
